# GraphAPIError: (#613) Calls to mailbox_fql have exceeded the rate of 300 calls per 600 seconds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an application that access Facebook's inbox every 30 seconds.

The first few calls work - but after that I keep getting the "GraphAPIError: (#613) Calls to mailbox_fql have exceeded the rate of 300 calls per 600 seconds." error.

There's no way I'm accessing the inbox 300 times in under 10 minutes.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing multiple accounts? That rate limit is per application not per user.

Comment: What do you mean?
If my application has 100000 active users, this means almost no one can check its inbox...